# WordPress blog in Subdirectory of Django website on a CPanel Host

Tags: django, wordpress, cpanel, subdirectory, wsgi

As I read articles and questions online, I believe it is possible; My main question is how to achieve this goal?

I have Django Website with some urls on my domain (I use Setup Python App plugin on CPanel). I can simply achieve this using a subdomain, but I want to run my WordPress blog on a subdirectory, but every url that is not registered in urls.py will raise an error.

What's the best way to reach this goal?

What are the steps that I need to take to reach it?

I will be more than greatful if you point me towards the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was going through this and posted a question with the opposite issue having wordpress in the base directory and django in a sub directory.

You must edit the .htaccess file in the public_html directory to redirect your urls properly:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# Add the following line to exclude the /excluded_directory/ path
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/excluded_directory/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This .htaccess code assumes wordpress is in the base directory. If it is django in the base directory then would do the opposite.